# Найти минимальную дату из трех в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Найти минимальную дату из трех в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ
 min(D, 31.12.2017, today())
Минимальную - значит самую раннюю
D - любая входящая дата в формате   ДД.ММ.ГГГГ

Comment: если вы пишите, что `d` это любая входящая, то `31.12.2017` это константа? зачем ее сравнивать с `today` тогда?

Comment: разверни все даты как строки в обратную сторону и сравни просто как строки

Answer (score 1):

Все просто:

```js
var now = new Date()
var day1 = new Date(2018, 07, 12);
var day2 = new Date(2018, 06, 12);
var day3 = new Date(2018, 05, 12);
if(day1 < day2 && day1 < day3){
  alert(1);
}
else if(day2 < day3 && day2 < day1){
  alert(2);
}
else if(day3 < day2 && day3 < day1){
  alert(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу 2 пути, какой лучше в плане универсальности формата дат и кросс-браузерности может подскажут в комментариях

```
var day1 = new Date("31.12.2017");
...
...
min=Math.min(day1,day2,day3);
```

.parse()

```
var day1 = Date.parse("31.12.2017");
...
...
min=Math.min(day1,day2,day3);
```